# Event binding with jquery live() function

Tags: jquery

First here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="foreground">
    <button type="button" id="go">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="background">
    <p>You are on the background</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#go").click(function (e) {
        var $q = $(this);
        var $vazy = $('<button type="button" id="vazy"> Vazy </button>');
        var $loc = $('<input type="text" id="placename" placeholder="Location"/>');

        $vazy.insertAfter($q);
        $loc.insertAfter($q);
        $q.hide();

        e.stopPropagation();

    });

    $("#vazy").live("click", function () {
        alert('k');
        //$("#foreground").hide();
        //$("#background").show();
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    display: none;
}
```

[jsFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/ndanvery/xzG5D/)

The problem is at the line 15 where the button with the ID `#vazy` seems not to respond to my click event even with the live binding. 
Am I missing something?

Thanks for any response :)

Comment: `live()` was flawed and rightly deprecated. Prefer the new `on()` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, please add all code to your post incase the sites you link to go down in the future :). Thanks.

Comment: Oh right, I should update my knowledge (and my book btw haha).

Comment: @Matt Thanks Matt! I will sure remember your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    $("body").on("click","#vazy" function () {
    alert('k');
    //$("#foreground").hide();
    //$("#background").show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated..

Try using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('body').on("click",'#vazy', function () {
    alert('k');
});
```

Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agFTq/)

Answer (score 1):

live is deprecated use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event to dynamically added elements. You can delegate event to parent of the element or document.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xzG5D/3/)**

```
$(document).on("click", "#vazy", function () {
    alert('k');
    //$("#foreground").hide();
    //$("#background").show();
});
```

#### delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet:
{foreground is the closest static container, use it as delegate}

```
$("#foreground").on("click",'#vazy', function () {...});
```